# How do I run Angular2 app with java EE backend maven build and glassfish server?

Tags: java, angular, maven, glassfish

I have to build and serve an angular2 app with maven and Glassfish server. I have a java EE backend.

[App structure looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4B4Hg.png)

[image]

And pom.xml looks like this:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    ro.nttdata
    candidate
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    war
    candidate
    
        src
        
            
                maven-compiler-plugin
                3.6.1
                
                    1.8
                    1.8
                
            
            
                maven-war-plugin
                3.0.0
                
                    WebContent

```
        <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.5</version>
     <configuration>
       <filesets>
         <fileset>
           <directory>candidate-client/dist/</directory>
           <includes>
             <include>*</include>
           </includes>
         </fileset>
       </filesets>
     </configuration>
   </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>

            <configuration>
                <nodeVersion>v6.10.1</nodeVersion>
                <npmVersion>4.4.1</npmVersion>
                <workingDirectory>candidate-client/</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>npm run build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>

                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run build</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-client-build</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/${project.artifactId}/</outputDirectory>
                        <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>candidate-client/dist/</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>*/**</include>
                                    <include>*.html</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
             </executions>
            </plugin>



    </plugins>

</build>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>

        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>

        <version>2.10.4</version>


    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>

        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>

        <version>2.25.1</version>


    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I managed to build the app that generates the dist folder and to move the files to target, but when I run it on server I get 404. I am new with maven...I'm thankful for every suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

pom configurations look fine.

In your index.html file you need to add base path like

```
<base href="/appname">
```